# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n$ x $n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a diagonal matrix with different diagonal entries. If $B$ is a matrix such that $AB=BA$, show that $B$ is also diagonal.

I think the problem use decomposition, but I stuck to prove it

Comment: no decomposition. Just write the two matrices

Comment: Perhaps you should use a more descriptive title?

Comment: Try an example with $2\times 2$ matrices.  In other words, let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&0\\0&a_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}r&s\\t&u\end{bmatrix}$.  Then, write out $AB$ and $BA$.

Comment: can yo give the solution?

Comment: No, we don't give solutions here. Just tips. Try working out his example and see if you can recognise some things.

Comment: so, give your tips maybe @MitchellFaas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ the entries of $A$ and $B$. Then the entry at place $(i,j)$ of $AB=BA$ can be written
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj}
$$
Since $A$ is diagonal, the sum on the left hand side is
$$
a_{ii}b_{ij}
$$
and the sum on the right hand side is
$$
b_{ij}a_{jj}
$$
Thus we have
$$
(a_{ii}-a_{jj})b_{ij}=0
$$
and, when $i\ne j$, …